# How do you read in a video file frame by frame in OpenCV?

Tags: c, opencv

Using the C API (not C++), how do you read in a simple video file frame by frame, and pass this frame (as a CvMat*) off for processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
CvCapture* cap = cvCreateFileCapture(MyVideoFile);
if (!cap) { /* handle error */ }

for(;;) {
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(cap);
    if (!frame) { /* EOF */ break; }

    CvMat tempMat;
    CvMat* myMat = cvGetMat( frame, &tempMat, 0, 0);

    // use myMat

    // Note: Don't free the frame returned by cvQueryFrame!
}   

cvReleaseCapture(&cap);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why not free the frame returned by cvQueryFrame?

Comment: Because [the documentation](http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm#decl_cvQueryFrame) says so. Clone the image (or the mat) if you want to modify it.